# How to test a destructor for a binary tree?

Tags: c, testing

A naive recursive destructor for a binary tree looks like this:

```c
void destroy_tree(Node *tree) {
    if (tree->left != NULL)
        destroy_tree(tree->left);
    if (tree->right != NULL)
        destroy_tree(tree->right);
    free(tree);
}
```

The question is: how to test such code? How to ensure that the traversal is correct? How to check that all nodes are indeed deleted?

Comment: Add a `printf("%p\n", tree)` before  the `free` call and also add a similar debug print in front of the code that allocates each node. Then compare the pointer list outputs to verify they have all been freed.

Comment: Also a good idea to do a `printf` in the construction to do the comparison

Comment: You could use valgrind to check if all the memory allocated is freed

Comment: @jamesdlin - I think you meant `tree == NULL`

Comment: As an aside, it'd be better to make destroy_tree do `if (tree == NULL) return`; first. Then you could get rid of the list and right checks, and your function would have the same semantics as `free`.

Comment: @EdHeal Oops, yes. =)

Answer (score 0):

As @jamesdin suggested the code would look like

```
void destroy_tree(Node *tree) {
    if (tree == NULL) {
       return;
    }
    destroy_tree(tree->left);
    destroy_tree(tree->right);
    free(tree);
}
```

Sorry for making this an answer - but it makes it readable - so please do not vote either way